# Use jquery/ajax to call a c# (or any other .net) function in another project within the same solution

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, project, solution

Does anyone know if it's possible to use jquery/ajax to call a c# (or any other .net) function in another project within the same solution?

Let's say that the solution's name is ExampleSolution , the name of the project from which I call the target function is Project.Source and the name of the target project is Project.Target,
and the name of the target function is `TargetFunction()`.

I've tried following in an `.js file` in the `Project.Source`:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/ExampleSolution/Project.Target/TargetFunction',            
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                $(document.body).append(data);
            }
   });
```

Then I've modified the url-line in several ways but never succeed.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: You need to write something (eg, an MVC action) that accepts HTTP requests and calls the method.

Comment: `ScriptMethod` attribute maybe but your server side code will have to handle passing the call over to the library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your fast answers.

I found a solution for the problem and I'd like to share it just in case anybody faces the same problem in the future.

In the .js file before I call the $.ajax function I create a variable with help of window.location which points to the url to the targetfunction of the running target-project and use the variable in the ajax-function. So you don't point to another project. You point to url of running project.

Just as easy as it sounds.

Below follows the solution:

```
    var url = window.location = 'http://localhost:13105/TargetFunction';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            $(document.body).append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice dirty solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can only call functions in the Code Behind because they're being registered by the web server.

If you want to have a function accessible outside the Code Behind it needs to be registered as a ASMX or WCF service.

See [Creating and Consuming Your First WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service) for setting up a WCF Service.

Once it is setup and running you can use Ajax to call the methods just like you would in the Code Behind.

```
$.ajax({
        //Path to WCF Server and Target Method
        url: "http://localhost:PORT/wcfsvc/FooService.svc/Foo",
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $(document.body).append(data);
        }
});
```

See also: [Consuming WCF from jQuery as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904609/consuming-wcf-from-jquery-as-json)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No, it isn't possible."  Front-end code (like jQuery and AJAX) run on the client's machine, but C# functions are back-end and run on the server.  There's no direct connection between them.

---

The longer answer is "Not directly, but there are ways to do something similar."  Your easiest option is to use AJAX to POST to another controller/action on your server and then process the response.  This is *close* to what you were doing, but you were slightly off.  Rather than the url being a function, the url has to be an actual url on your website.  Using `/Functions/CallTargetFunction` as an example, you would then create a controller like this:

```
public class FunctionsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CallTargetFunction()
    {
        return Content(TargetFunction());
    }
}
```

Note that doing this means **anyone** who visits `http://yoursite.com/Functions/CallTargetFunction` will get the result of that function.