# Accesing WCF web service from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have created a WCF project. The url is`URL:http://localhost:4501/MathOperationService/`

I have two methods in my service: `topla(x,y)` and `carp(x,y)`. I have created a client project in Visual Studio 2012. I can access my wcf service from this client project, because I use a proxy file accessing my service methods from the client. Now my question is..

How can I acces my service from Jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904609/consuming-wcf-from-jquery-as-json

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article, it discusses decorating your WCF services with REST URI templates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb412172(v=vs.90).aspx